# What extensions do I need to create a Windows 10 app using JavaScript in Visual Studio Code or should I just install Visual Studio instead?

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

What extensions do I need to create a Windows 10 app using JavaScript in Visual Studio Code? Or should I just install Visual Studio instead? I already use VSC and was looking for the easiest process.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to reach about [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/), but it's not and extension, it's a library.

No extension to IDE will create an app for you